# How do I make the Windows command prompt opacity settings permament?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, display-settings, opacity

My question is super simple, although somewhat specific and I can't find anything online.

So I want to change the color and opacity of my Windows 10 Command Prompt. I've been able to do that just fine, but for some reason, while the colors are saved and remain permament, the opacity of the cmd.exe window goes back to default settings (which is 100%) every time.

I know it's not that big of a deal, but I'd like to be able to have the opacity settings remain permanent. Is that possible and if so, how do I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works OK for me on Win 10 V1803, i ran start > cmd and right-clicked the icon, selected Open File Location to take me to C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools\ then set opacity to 80%. Persists when I re-launch CMD from start.

Comment: @spikey_richie Ok. It's strange. For me it doesn't work for some reason. When I go back to Properties, it still shows opacity at 85%, yet when I run cmd, it's at 100%...

Comment: Windows > Settings > Colors > Do you have 'Transparency effects' set to On? Alternatively search for 'Opacity' then jump to 'Show Transparency in Windows'